# Login with Django and Ajax does nothing

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

Here is my form:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id = 'login_button'>Login</button>
</form>
```

And the script:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    var login_button = $('#login_button')

    login_button.click(function(){
        var username = $('#username').val()
        var password = $('#password').val()


        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'td_app:do_login' %}',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                'username': username,
                'password': password
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                console.log(data.result)
            }
        }).done(function (){
            console.log(data.result)
        })
    })
</script>
```

In my views.py:

```
def do_login(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    password = request.GET.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    data = {}

    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            data['result'] = 'success'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('td_app:index'))

    else:
        data['result'] = 'failed'

return JsonResponse(data)
```

And finally my urls.py:

```
url(r'^api/do_login/$', views.do_login, name='do_login')
```

However all of these doesn't work and it doesn't even give me any errors. It just completely refreshes the whole page and does nothing. I tried putting alerts but on the `success` and `done` section but it doesn't show it up.

Any thoughts/advices? Thanks a lot!

### UPDATE

I tried putting a `print` on my views.py:

```
def do_login(request):
    print('A login was attempted!')

    username = request.GET.get('username')
    password = request.GET.get('password')
```

But when my login executes from the ajax, the print isn't called. It's not giving me any errors too like 'a connection to your view is invalid etc'.

### UPDATE 2

I tried changing my jquery script (thanks to @AlwaysHelping):

```
login_button.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        var username = $('#username').val()
        var password = $('#password').val()


        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'td_app:do_login' %}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'username': username,
                'password': password
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                alert('asdasdas')
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('there was an error')
            }
        })
```

I changed the `type: 'get'` to `type: 'POST'` and also added an `error` section. Now when I click the button it gives me the error alert, and when I check the network console it says `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/api/do_login/ 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` in your click function. You have not define a button type in your form so its  by default as `type="submit"` - Use `type="button"` OR `e.preventDefault()` in your click function.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks!  I tried it and now the page doesn't refreshes anymore. However it still does nothing.

Comment: I think you need to check the browser network console and see if ajax is being called at all or not. - You also do not need `.done` - if you have success function in your `$.ajax.`

Comment: Also your request is type: is `get` - i am sure its should be `POST`- Change that to POST to see the form data in `views.py`

Comment: Are you sure the server is configured to do a post request in the backend ? Are you always `get` when you do an ajax ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping `Are you sure the server is configured to do a post request in the backend` I don't know about this sir/ma'am

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222141/discussion-between-always-helping-and-dran-dev).

Comment: @AlwaysHelping forgive me I was able to reply very late, the power went out here in our place

Comment: No no please do not be sorry. Is it all good now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use `preventDefault` method stop the page form reloading each time using `e.preventDefault()` in your click function.

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Secondly, you have a `get` request in your in your ajax but you are doing a POST instead so change that to POST to send `values` to `django` views.

```
type: POST
```

Lastly, you do not need an `.done` method in your `ajax` since you are using success function which should be enough.

Comment: @DranDev you are welcome. Let me know if you get stuck - i will be happy to reply back and help you out further if needed.